# axios firebase refresh token authorization header not override

Tags: firebase, react-native, axios

I'm trying to refresh token(firebase) in react native without success. It add the new token but in this way

```
Authorization Bearer old_token, Bearer new_token
```

Expected behaviour

```
Authorization Bearer new_token
```

Here is my code, we can see the instance, interceptor for append current token to all request and finally the interceptor for the refresh token. I don't know what I'm missing.

```
const customConfig: AxiosRequestConfig = {
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000',
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
    },
    responseType: 'json',
};
const instance: any = axios.create(
    customConfig,
);

// interceptor to put token to all request
instance.interceptors.request.use(
    async (config: any) => {
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
        if (token) {
            config.headers.authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
            console.log("config.headers.authorization", config.headers.authorization)
        }
        return config;
    },
    (error: any) => {
        Promise.reject(error);
    },
);

// interceptor to handle refresh token
instance.interceptors.response.use((response: any) => {
    return response;
},
    function (error: any) {
        console.log("error en axios", error)
        const originalRequest = error.config;
        if (!error.response) {
            return Promise.reject('Network Error');
        }
        if ((error.response.status === 401) && !originalRequest._retry) {

            originalRequest._retry = true;

            return firebase.auth().currentUser?.getIdTokenResult(false).then((res) => {
                AppStorage.setToken(res.token).then(() => { console.log('Token saved'); });
     
                const addToken = 'Bearer ' + res.token;
                instance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = addToken;
                
                originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] = addToken;
                
                return axios(originalRequest);
            });
        }
        return Promise.reject(error);
    },
);
```

Comment: If you're using a provided Firebase Auth SDK, you don't have to write code to refresh the auth token.  The SDK will automatically refresh it, and you can receive a callback when then happens using onIdTokenChanged. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onidtokenchanged

Comment: I'm not refreshing firebase auth token. My backend is protected with firebase token so I need to attach firebase token to all my backend calls. My problem is described above instead of get Authorization Bearer newToken , I get Authorization Bearer oldToken, Bearer newToken.

Comment: may be missing of async in error callback at the last interceptor :)

Comment: I'm using promises there so no need async